# Div size depending on text with corner left to right translation on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, text, translation

I'm having a problem with a div translation I'm trying to achieve.

As you can see on this CodePen : https://codepen.io/Rojiraan/pen/PJoMvr , everything works as I want, or almost.
My only problem is that if my text is longer or smaller than what is actually written, the div isn't returning correctly at his left corner place, so the arrow isn't exactly horizontally aligned.

I think adding a "calc" on the ".translate" class or doing some JQuery formulas may repair the problem, but I don't really see how.

So here is my simple css class concerned :

```
.translate
{
transform: translateX(-89%);
}
```

And my complete JQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {      

$('.arrow').click(function(){  
      $('aside').toggleClass('translate');

      //Just for rotating the arrow when clicking
      $('.arrow').toggleClass('rotate');
  });

});
```

---

### **EDIT**

I forgot to add something very important into my CodePen that was causing the initial problem. In my real page, this "aside" html element was appearing after a 1s delay using "animation-delay: 1s;", so the CSS aside element was in fact looking like this :

```
aside
{
    position: fixed;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 45px;
    height: 54px;
    background-color: #ff8686;
    left: -1500px;

    color: white;
    font: 22px Roboto;

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: inline-flex;

    transition: 0.5s;
    animation-name: asideelement;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes asideelement
{
    from {left:-1500px;}
    to {left:0px;}
}
```

So adding...

```
.translate
{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    left: 45px;
}
```

...was also problematic because the "@keyframes" seemed to be more important than the rest of the code. I tried adding "left: 45px!important", that was working in Firefox (with jittering), but not in Chrome.
So finally, instead of this I simply decided to go full JQuery and add a new class :

```
//JQuery code added :
setTimeout(function(){
    $('aside').toggleClass('apparitionAside');
}, 1000);

/* CSS code added : */
.apparitionAside
{
    left: 0px;
}
```

Here is a CodePen illustrating everything : https://codepen.io/Rojiraan/pen/QqwjzJ

Comment: @SilverSurfer No...t really doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of translateX dynamic value, go for full width and than add a left position;

```
.translate {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    left: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so that was this easy, thank you very much ! ;-)